# Immigration delay at Newark airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, ewr

How long time does it take to get through Immigration at Terminal B in Newark these days?

Arriving from Oslo, Norway, going to Ft. Lauderdale. I have 1h and 35min.

Comment: that seems incredibly tight.  What time of day?

Comment: Remember that you'll also have to collect checked luggage, pass customs, and recheck your luggage/escort it to the bag drop. Then you'll have to cross security again.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Due to the lack of all details, am voting to close this question as it is too broad to answer.

Comment: @pnuts Its not an exact *answer*, is it ? Feel free to flag it.

Comment: You can look at recent wait time here http://awt.cbp.gov/. You can look up a few previous weeks at the same weekday and time of day and that should give a good sense of current situation unless there is an unusual event (holiday, etc) on your travel day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With immigration clearance, it takes as long as it takes. Newark is often used as a Port of Entry by many non US citizens flying into the US. There are just too many factors involved. If it helps, from what I know about non US citizens arriving in extremely busy POEs such as JFK- NY, Dallas and Atlanta, usually, regular tourists will clear immigration in about an hour.

If you are on a single leg ticket, and if you miss your flight, you will be put on to the next available flight. In the US, mostly, if someone misses a domestic flight they are given an opportunity to fly in the next available flight if seats are available.

Comment: And for US citizens, we would have difficulty in making it through in that amount of time _and_ making a connection. I can attest to that for Newark, JFK, and ATL. Most recent ATL int'l arrival took just under 2 hours and I wasn't connecting.

Comment: @pnuts Even if someone cleared immigration yesterday (or even a few hours ago) at *Newark* no one can **guarantee** a time window for immigration clearance. If you think someone can, you are only kidding yourself. All one can do is give an estimate. By comparing it with even busier port of entries, I am only trying to be helpful. A broad question can only get broad answers

Comment: Thanks for useful answers and comments. I'm on a single leg ticket, but I won't the chance - I'll change my ticket to Ft. Lauderdale :)